# Is this curl post or get?

Tags: php, curl

I have a php code:

```
$url='https://payment.testingfc.com/TokenPayment.jsp?merchantId='. $merchantid .'&data='.$desEncryptedData; 

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$auth = curl_exec($curl);
```

Is this curl POST or GET?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specify POST.. it is GET.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a POST like this:

```
<?php

$post_data = array('merchantId'=>$merchantid, 'data'=>$desEncryptedData);

$curl = curl_init('https://payment.testingfc.com/TokenPayment.jsp');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

?>
```